# find intersection elements in arrays in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to construct a function intersection that compares input arrays and returns a new array with elements found in all of the inputs.
    The following solution works if in each array the numbers only repeat once, otherwise it breaks. Also, I don't know how to simplify and not use messy for loops:

```
function intersection(arrayOfArrays) {
  let joinedArray = [];
  let reducedArray = [];
  for (let iOuter in arrayOfArrays) {
    for (let iInner in arrayOfArrays[iOuter]) {
      joinedArray.push(arrayOfArrays[iOuter][iInner]);
    }
    return joinedArray;
  }


  for (let i in joinedArray.sort()) {
    if (joinedArray[i] === joinedArray[ i - (arrayOfArrays.length - 1)]) {
      reducedArray.push(joinedArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return reducedArray;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of output you desire when an array of arrays is passed to the function?

Comment: One more thing, the first time the `for (let iOuter ..) ...` loop runs the function returns a value `joinedArray`, since the function has returned a value it no longer runs and the loop as well is complete after only 1 run.

Comment: you want to get the elements which exist in all arrays right ?

Comment: You should have a look at javascript built-in functions to loop into arrays (`forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `filter` ...). They will become very handy to you and make your code cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try thhis:-**

```
function a1(ar,ar1){
    x = new Set(ar)
    y = new Set(ar1)
    var result = [] 
    for (let i of x){
        if (y.has(i)){
            result.push(i)
        }
    }
    if (result){return result}
    else{ return 0}
}
var a= [3,4,5,6]
var b = [8,5,6,1]
console.log(a1(a,b)) //output=> [5,6]
```

Comment: Question is about an array of arrays, not just 2 arrays. How would you update your function to do that?

Comment: yess but in qust. it mentioned comparing input arrays hence i have given that sorry for miss understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this snippet will be useful

```js
var a = [2, 3, 9];
var b = [2, 8, 9, 4, 1];
var c = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 9];
var d = [1, 2]

function intersect() {
  // create an empty array to store any input array,All the comparasion
  // will be done against this one
  var initialArray = [];
  // Convert all the arguments object to array
  // there can be n number of supplied input array
  // sorting the array by it's length. the shortest array 
  //will have at least all the elements
  var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length
  });
  initialArray = x[0];
  // loop over remaining array
  for (var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
    var tempArray = x[i];
    // now check if every element of the initial array is present
    // in rest of the arrays
    initialArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
      // if there is some element which is present in intial arrat but not in current array
      // remove that eleemnt.
      //because intersection requires element to present in all arrays
      if (x[i].indexOf(item) === -1) {
        initialArray.splice(index, 1)
      }

    })

  }
  return initialArray;
}

console.log(intersect(a, b, c, d))
```

Comment: Your function has some issues: you do not handle the case where `x` is empty, and you `splice` an array while looping into it with `forEach`... this is a typical case for `filter`

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice way of doing it using `reduce` to intersect through your array of arrays and then `filter` to make remaining values unique.

```
function intersection(arrayOfArrays) {
    return arrayOfArrays
        .reduce((acc,array,index) => { // Intersect arrays
            if (index === 0)
                return array;
            return array.filter((value) => acc.includes(value));
        }, [])
        .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index) // Make values unique
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each array and count the frequency of occurrence of the number in an object where the key is the number in the array and its property being the array of occurrence in an array. Using the generated object find out the lowest frequency of each number and check if its value is more than zero and add that number to the result.

```js
function intersection(arrayOfArrays) {
  const frequency = arrayOfArrays.reduce((r, a, i) => {
    a.forEach(v => {
      if(!(v in r))
        r[v] = Array.from({length:arrayOfArrays.length}).fill(0);
      r[v][i] = r[v][i] + 1;
    });
    return r;
  }, {});
  
  return Object.keys(frequency).reduce((r,k) => {
    const minCount = Math.min(...frequency[k]);
    if(minCount) {
      r = r.concat(Array.from({length: minCount}).fill(+k));
    }
    return r;
    }, []);
}
console.log(intersection([[2,3, 45, 45, 5],[4,5,45, 45, 45, 6,7], [3, 7, 5,45, 45, 45, 45,7]]))
```

Comment: Your approach offers an optimization in case arrays contain many (many) occurrences of a set of few elements. The question asks for a generic and simple approach.